# Read file's content after requesting

Tags: objective-c, xcode, web-services

I am new to iOS programming. Currently, I am trying to read response come from the following request using objective-c:

> http://www.google.com/transliterate?langpair=ja-Hira|ja&text=%E3%81%B8%E3%82%93%E3%81%8B%E3%82%93

However, the response is not in JSON but in txt file (if we request the above url the txt file will be automatically downloaded).

Is there any possible way to read this txt file?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You possibly have to save text file in documents directory. Read its contents using file programming.

```
NSString* path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"filename" 
                                                 ofType:@"txt"];

NSString* content = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:path
                                              encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding
                                                 error:NULL];
```

Please refer below Apple resource link for more details.

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Strings/Articles/readingFiles.html